# Что такое Хэш Код?

Tags: поддержка

Здесь иногда встречается упоминание Хэш Кода, что это такое?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ХэшКод — это ныне покойный русскоязычный аналог [англоязычного Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

[image: Экранный снимок сайта hashcode.ru]

Он примечателен тем, что [в 2015-м году переехал на платформу SO](https://vc.ru/11103-knowledge-network-stack-overflow), в результате чего и образовался тот сайт, на котором мы сейчас находимся (Stack Overflow на русском).

Иными словами, все участники, вопросы и ответы переехали сюда, после чего ХэшКод был отключен. На данный момент он [доступен исключительно через интернет-архив](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http:hashcode.ru).

Кстати, такая же участь постигла и другой сайт «[Сети Знаний](http://web.archive.org/web/20140707164055/http://sezn.ru:80/)», *russ.hashcode.ru* — теперь это [rus.stackexchange.com](https://rus.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Из забавного, в какой-то момент hashcode решил разослать активным участникам футболки, так вот - данные собирались еще на хешкоде, но когда футболка пришла на ней уже было "stackoverflow на русском"

Comment: @aknew проверьте на изнаночной стороне.

Comment: И только русскоязычную математику все никак не постигнет сия участь)