# Что случилось с сайтом "∞ Математика"?

Tags: поддержка

Сижу на сайте [∞ Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru). 
Люблю математику и сам сайт, смотрю там интересные вопросы и ответы. Но сайт как-то отстал во времени и не развивается никак. Дизайн старый и совсем уж не похож на развитый Stackoverflow.
Что случилось с сайтом? Почему редактирование прекратилось?

Comment: Ничего не случилось. Сайт работает, даже не в режиме "только для чтения", хотя активность невысокая. Просто ХэшКод и Русский язык перешли "под крыло" Stack Exchange, а Математика - нет. См. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7368/1365

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Так как Николасу не хватит смелости сказать правду, то скажу я.

Математический подсайт не был принят в состав Stack Exchange, потому что он не соответствовал стандартам SE: траффик, качество ответов, активность юзеров, процент отвеченных вопросов — параметров много, примерный список можно найти на Area 51. Соответственно, он никогда не будет переведён на движок SE.

В рамках Stack Exchange, если бы такой сайт пробился через Area 51, его бы уже удалили и законсервировали в виде бэкапа, как поступают с другими проваленными бетами.

Руководителем Сети Знаний был Николас, сейчас он полностью посвящает себя работе в Stack Exchange, на развитие старых сайтов у него времени нет и не будет.

В целом, сайт Математика сейчас заброшен и находится в статусе "никому не надо, но удалить жалко". Можете пользоваться, но ни на что не расссчитывайте.

Comment: Я не знаю насчёт трафика и всего остального, но администрация сети Stack Exchange давно приняла решения пока не создавать неанглоязычные сообщества, которые не будут аналогом Stack Overflow. Единственным исключением из правил был "Русский язык". Поэтому это совсем не так.

Comment: @Vadim Если они так сделали, значит, их заинтересовали показатели РЯ, а М - нет. Случай Сети Знаний явно обрабатывался индивидуально, общие принципы неприменимы.

Comment: Возникает вопрос, откуда вы знаете, чего и кому не хватает

Comment: @Kromster Имеющий уши да услышит, имеющий глаза да увидит.

Comment: Имеющий крылья да взлетит, а небо голубое, ну да

Answer (score 5):

Лучше могут ответить авторы, я же предположу, что после того, как сообщество программистов приютил StackOverflow, а Николаса взяли к себе на работу, развивать Математику стало некому.